# Ext.data.JsonP.request timeout

Tags: sencha-touch

I have written a controller. When I click the button from view, this controller generic 'button' is called as follows:

```
        'button': {
            tap: function() {



           Ext.data.JsonP.request({
                    url: 'http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv',
                    params: {
                        s: '^BSESN',
                        f: 'nsl1op'   
                    },
                    callbackKey: 'callback',
                    scope: this,
                    success: function( res, req ) {
                        Ext.example.msg('Sucess!', 'CSV file successfully generated.');
                        Ext.data.StoreManager.get('Files').load();
                    },
                    failure: function( res, req ) {
                        console.log('Failed to load csv file.');
                    }
                });

....
....
....
```

It timesout and failure is called "Failed to load csv file."

The original URL I am using is "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=^BSESN&f=nsl1op".

I would like know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're requesting a CSV file via JSONP.

The file will be injected into the DOM via a '' tag (which is how JSONP works), but since it's not a valid JavaScript file, your callback (`callbackKey: 'callback'`) is never executed, so Sencha Touch will fire the timeout handler, seeing the callback has not been fired by the injected `<script>` tag.

You probably need to change the URL to something that is actually JSONP (iow valid JavaScript wrapped in a callback), not a CSV file.